# Use Internet explorer proxy settings

Tags: go, proxy

I'm developing a go application that need to connect to the internet. I use the `http.ProxyFromEnvironment` transport to auto-detect the proxy on linux, but it falls short on windows.

How can I retrieve the proxy settings of Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Those values can be found in the registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

Here is a simple library that allows you to retrieve those settings easily (disclaimer: I re-wrote most of this library recently): https://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-ieproxy

You can transparently use `http.ProxyFromEnvironment` by calling `OverrideEnvWithStaticProxy()` in an `init` function:

```
func init() {
    ieproxy.OverrideEnvWithStaticProxy()
    http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Proxy = http.ProxyFromEnvironment
}
```

Comment: Is that still the recommended solution in 2019, or does go have some out-of-the-box support now?